# jquery doesn't regonzise div width sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Idea is to get the width of an element and depending on the size do something.

```
function featureSliderLoad(){
    var feature = setInterval(function(){ 
        var adWidth = jQuery('#leaderboard div iframe').width();

        if(adWidth != 0 && adWidth != null){
            if(adWidth > 728){
                Do something
            } else {
                Do something else
            }
        }

        if(jQuery('#leaderboard div iframe').width() > 100){
            clearInterval(feature);
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

This works most of the time but every now and then it does not. If use onload like:

```
jQuery(window).load(function featureSliderLoad()
```

It then works 100% of the time but I shouldn't have to because I have:

```
if(adWidth != 0 && adWidth != null)
```

Which should take care of the issue of the element not being loaded and coming up 0 or null.

Does anyone see a problem with the code that would stop it from working when I don't use (window).load ?

Thanks

Comment: it would be better.. if you post your html too..

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting questions

Comment: Could be possible that after 2000ms iframe still haven't loaded due to some latency sometimes.

Comment: If images are involved then their size won't be included until they have loaded which would account for difference using `window.load`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the script is being executed before the DOM has fully rendered in the page. If you are injecting Div elements into the page post rendering you may also see an issue. This is why your snippet `Query(window).load(...` works as it prevents it from being called until the DOM is finished rendering.

I would wrap your jQuery in a `documet.ready` function  or use what you have above to prevent the code from executing until after the DOM has fully rendered. Otherwise it will be hit or miss.

Comment: I thought by calling the function every 2 seconds and not having it executed until the width was not 0 or null and then ending the script after would fix that issue. I'll go with the one of the above as you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it would work sometimes and not work at other times is because there is no guarantee that the window element and all of the elements contained in it have loaded before you call the function.  If you're not using jQuery's load event ([jquery load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)) or something similar to delay the call to your function until after the HTML has loaded, then your HTML is in an unknown state when your function is called; therefore, your function will have unpredictable results.